# sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, dependencies

i want to run the following command :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

all packages downloads fine expect 1 package because the contain `"proxy"` word in the link and my ISP block it

i can give him another link to download package from or i can use some `VPN` programs like Vidalia but i can't install anything!!

> so how can i specify a link or install a software